# Can't read mahout output of PFPGrowth

Tags: apache, hadoop, mahout, mahout-recommender

i am successfully running Parallel FPGroth Algorithm of Apache mahout on top of hadoop.
But the generetaed output text files are not readable as you can see below

SEQorg.apache.hadoop.io.TextDorg.apache.mahout.fpm.pfpgrowth.convertors.string.TopKStringPatterns������3G9��y'����e�����1���2�����������1���������t�5�1���������t�4�1�����������1�4227�����������3�1�����������1�3476���������t�1�1340���������h�1�5795���������N�1�2701���������K�1�3610���������@�1�2106��������
...

Running RecommenderJob and ItemSimilarityJob with the same input file generates correct 
output files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These output files are sequence files, not text files. They contains key/value pairs of type `<Text, TopKStrinPatterns>`

You can get hadoop to read the sequence files and output the textual versions of these objects using the fs shell command, combined with -text and -libjars:

```
hadoop fs -libjars /path/to/mahout/lib.jar -text /path/to/hdfs/output/part*
```

If you want these files to be text rather than sequence then you'll need to amend the driver which runs the job, and change the job to use `TextOutputFormat`, rather than `SequenceFileOutputFormat`:

```
// job.setOutputFormat(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
```